# Bluetooth disconnects after few minutes randomly after 21.04 upgrade

Tags: bluetooth, 21.04, disconnect

As title suggests I have a bluetooth headset which is randomly getting disconnected after few minutes, this only happens after I upgraded to 21.04 yesterday. I’m not sure how to troubleshoot this so any feedback would be nice.

Just some logs just as it disconnected:

```
Jun 10 10:28:14 laptop-gabriel rtkit-daemon[1213]: Supervising 13 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jun 10 10:28:14 laptop-gabriel rtkit-daemon[1213]: Supervising 13 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jun 10 10:28:16 laptop-gabriel rtkit-daemon[1213]: Supervising 13 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jun 10 10:28:16 laptop-gabriel rtkit-daemon[1213]: Supervising 13 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jun 10 10:28:21 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:21:244] info: [RTM] (TAMHY3N9K) Processed 1 user_invalidated event(s) over 33.04ms
Jun 10 10:28:22 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:22:380] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313702.379 Flannel users/info called with reason: flannel-call:users/info
Jun 10 10:28:22 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:22:381] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313702.379 Flannel users/info is ENQUEUED
Jun 10 10:28:22 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:22:381] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313702.379 Flannel users/info is ACTIVE
Jun 10 10:28:22 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:22:646] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313702.379 Flannel users/info is RESOLVED
Jun 10 10:28:23 laptop-gabriel wpa_supplicant[917]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-59 noise=9999 txrate=270000
Jun 10 10:28:38 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:38:297] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313718.288 Flannel users/info called with reason: flannel-call:users/info
Jun 10 10:28:38 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:38:298] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313718.288 Flannel users/info is ENQUEUED
Jun 10 10:28:38 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:38:299] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313718.288 Flannel users/info is ACTIVE
Jun 10 10:28:38 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:38:368] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313718.288 Flannel users/info is RESOLVED
Jun 10 10:28:39 laptop-gabriel wpa_supplicant[917]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-66 noise=9999 txrate=270000
Jun 10 10:28:40 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:40:433] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313720.432 Flannel users/info called with reason: flannel-call:users/info
Jun 10 10:28:40 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:40:434] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313720.432 Flannel users/info is ENQUEUED
Jun 10 10:28:40 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:40:435] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313720.432 Flannel users/info is ACTIVE
Jun 10 10:28:40 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:40:506] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313720.432 Flannel users/info is RESOLVED
Jun 10 10:28:43 laptop-gabriel wpa_supplicant[917]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-71 noise=9999 txrate=270000
Jun 10 10:28:50 laptop-gabriel wpa_supplicant[917]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=270000
Jun 10 10:28:51 laptop-gabriel acpid[871]: input device has been disconnected, fd 26
Jun 10 10:28:51 laptop-gabriel dbus-daemon[876]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.66" (uid=1000 pid=1348 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.4" (uid=0 pid=875 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
Jun 10 10:28:51 laptop-gabriel gsd-media-keys[1522]: Unable to get default sink
Jun 10 10:28:51 laptop-gabriel budgie-panel[1635]: gvc_mixer_stream_get_volume: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_STREAM (stream)' failed
Jun 10 10:28:51 laptop-gabriel budgie-panel[1635]: gvc_mixer_stream_get_is_muted: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_STREAM (stream)' failed
Jun 10 10:28:51 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:51:518] info: [RTM] (TAMHY3N9K) Processed 1 reaction_added event(s) over 55.50ms
Jun 10 10:28:55 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:55:376] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313735.375 Flannel users/info called with reason: flannel-call:users/info
Jun 10 10:28:55 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:55:376] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313735.375 Flannel users/info is ENQUEUED
Jun 10 10:28:55 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:55:377] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313735.375 Flannel users/info is ACTIVE
Jun 10 10:28:55 laptop-gabriel plank.desktop[10392]: [06/10/21, 10:28:55:446] info: [API-Q] (TAMHY3N9K) noversion-1623313735.375 Flannel users/info is RESOLVED
Jun 10 10:28:56 laptop-gabriel wpa_supplicant[917]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-68 noise=9999 txrate=270000
```

Edit:

Tried updating to latest linux-firmware but still getting disconnects:

```
Jul 09 09:09:31 laptop-gabriel acpid[877]: input device has been disconnected, fd 26
Jul 09 09:09:31 laptop-gabriel dbus-daemon[881]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.64" (uid=1000 pid=1348 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.3" (uid=0 pid=880 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
Jul 09 09:11:55 laptop-gabriel gsd-media-keys[1526]: Unable to get default sink
Jul 09 09:11:55 laptop-gabriel budgie-panel[1637]: gvc_mixer_stream_get_volume: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_STREAM (stream)' failed
Jul 09 09:11:55 laptop-gabriel budgie-panel[1637]: gvc_mixer_stream_get_is_muted: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_STREAM (stream)' failed
```

Comment: try updating your bluetooth drivers or try updating kernel

Comment: Try updating your Bluetooth drivers or kernel as @ShubhangKakkar said.

Comment: i need more info run lspci in terminal and tell what is version of your blurtooth card if it's bluetooth 4.0 then maybe your wifi and bluetooth are clashing and hence bluetooth devices are getting disconnects

Comment: it seems this is related to linux firmware version which is not updated yet for ubuntu, so have to wait for them to update it.

Comment: if all fails, try connecting it to another device, maybe it's a headset problem.

Comment: Works well with Android device, I'm also following this discussion I found: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/1155