# Bose NC 700 headphones bluetooth problems

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have problems pairing my Bose NC 700 headphones on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS via bluetooth. Every time I turn them on, they continue to connect and disconnect and don't work. I need to go to the bluetooth configurations and click on "remove device", then pair them again. Then they will work until I turn off the laptop or don't use them for some time.

Sometimes, using "systemctl restart bluetooth" helps. Is there a way to fix that permanently?

Comment: There is no such Ubuntu version as 18. What is the actual version?

Comment: thanks, I edited my question

Comment: @David besides your very useful critique, do you actually have any idea about a fix?

Comment: Maybe to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1349083/349837)? Could you try it on a newer version? Could be a live distro. Always after the same amount of time? Could be related to [autosuspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772056/keyboard-stops-working-ubuntu-16-04/813298#813298):
`sudo sh -c "echo -1 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend"`.
Did you check what happen on `journalctrl -xe`? Do you have `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` apt package installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have interference between WiFi and Bluetooth (which most often affects WiFi).
Please try a few things and report what you find/output info in the question.

1. Disabling WiFi. If this solves your problem, then depending on the adapters you have, a suitable configuration is possible.
2. Connecting with another bluetooth headset
3. Output of commands

   ```
   $ uname -a
   $ inxi -F
   $ systemctl status bluetooth.service
   $ bluetoothctl list
   $ bluetoothctl show
   $ bluetoothctl devices
   $ bluetoothctl paired-devices
   ```

Comment: 1) Disabling the WiFi does not solve the issue

Comment: 3) there are some errors in status bluetooth.service . I collected the output of the commands here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yOTrFNLC-aAcCx8L5cqN0gDNnRIuIkKxYIwXtFUUdoM/edit?usp=sharing